# Unity Edior Drawer Property Align

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

anyone knows how to deal with this problem?
I need to offset that grid without constant values. Can Unity Editor give me the position of the properties?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYhOG.png)

Answer (score 0):

The following line is the offset you need to move your element and mantain align with other properties

```
float offset = EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth - ((EditorGUI.indentLevel) * 15);
```

I found the answer [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/inspector-create-field-on-the-right.386991).

[image]